# Write to specific lines in a file using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline script file like below,

```
@Library(['github.com/shared-library']) _
pipeline {
  agent { label 'labelname' }

  stages {
      stage('Clean Workspace') {
          steps {
          // Clean the workspace
          }
      }
      stage('Checkout') {
          steps {
          // clone your project from Git/SVN etc
          }
      }
      stage('Build') {
          steps {
          // build, build stages can be made in parallel aswell
          // build stage can call other stages
          // can trigger other jenkins pipelines and copy artifact from that pipeline
          }
      }
      stage('Test') {
          steps {
          // Test (Unit test / Automation test(Selenium/Robot framework) / etc.)
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I now want to add the below script after the line containing "pipeline { " using groovy

```
options {
         buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
  }
```

and add the below line before the line containing "pipeline { " using groovy

```
def build_keep = 10
```

Kindly help.

Edit:
I am currently using,

```
def word = 'pipeline {'
int lineNum= 0
def f = new File('Test.groovy')
def lines = f.readLines()
new File('Test.groovy').eachLine{ line, ln -> 
  if(line.contains(word)){
    println "Line $ln"
    lineNum= "$ln"
    println "$lineNum"
    lines = lines.plus("$lineNum","options")
    f.text = lines.join('\n')
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the following output,

```
Line 3
3
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.plus() is applicable for argument types: (org.co
dehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, String) values: [3, options]
Possible solutions: plus(int, java.lang.Iterable), plus(java.lang.Object), plus(int, [Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.util.Collection), p
lus(java.lang.Object), plus(int, java.util.List)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.plus() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.g
roovy.runtime.GStringImpl, String) values: [3, options]
Possible solutions: plus(int, java.lang.Iterable), plus(java.lang.Object), plus(int, [Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.util.Collection), p
lus(java.lang.Object), plus(int, java.util.List)
at testing$_run_closure1.doCall(testing.groovy:15)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at testing.run(testing.groovy:8)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Please help

Comment: I think you missed closed brasses for pipeline {  }

Comment: Hi @np2807, so inside pipeline block is only the agent and stages block. I actually need to find the line containing this "pipeline {" and then add lines above and below it.

Comment: You have to read file, modify it using replaceAll or other approach, and write text back to file.